# Best place to clean-up App global resources?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdocument, nsapplication-delegate

**STOP PRESS** OK before you see the word `retainCount` in the following question, please skip to the **EDIT** at the bottom where I have stated that I have stopped using it.

My Cocoa App, which uses [MRR](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), creates many global resources, which I am loading in `main()`, before `NSApplicationMain()` is called.  As `NSApplicationMain()` doesn't return, I have hooked the clean-up of these resources using `atexit()`, like this:

```
atexit(cleanup);

if (![CocoaUtil initCocoaUtil] ||
    ![PreferenceController initPreferenceController] ||
    ![ResourceManager initResourceManager])
{
    criticalAlertPanel(@"Failed to initialize application",
                       @"Failed to initialize application");
    return 4;
}

retval = NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
```

However `cleanup()` is getting called before any of the views in my `NSDocument` subclass are `dealloc`'d (I have lack of log message to show this) and hence the reference counts of the objects in the global resources is sometimes `> 1`. I am being over-cautious and attempting to pre-empt memory leaks by using this method to release my global resources:

```
+ (void)fullRelease:(id)obj
             format:(NSString *)format, ...
{
    if (obj == nil)
        return;

    NSUInteger retainCount = [obj retainCount];
    if (retainCount > 1)
    {
        va_list va;
        va_start(va, format);
        NSString *objDesc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:va];
        logwrn(@"%@ has a reference count of %lu", objDesc, retainCount);
        [objDesc release];
    }

    while (retainCount > 0)
    {
        [obj release];
        retainCount--;
    }
}
```

My log shows the following:

```
12:15:04.954 INF -[AppController applicationDidFinishLaunching:] Application launched
12:15:06.702 INF -[AppController applicationShouldTerminate:] Application terminating
12:15:06.703 INF -[AppController applicationWillTerminate:] Application terminating
12:15:06.705 DBG cleanup Cleaning-up
12:15:06.705 INF +[ResourceManager finiResourceManager] Cleaning up
12:15:06.709 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[2] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.709 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[3] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.709 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[4] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.710 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[5] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.710 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[6] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.710 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[7] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.711 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[8] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.711 WRN +[CocoaUtil fullRelease:format:] _images[9] has a reference count of 2
12:15:06.721 DBG +[PreferenceController finiPreferenceController] Cleaning up
12:15:06.721 DBG +[CocoaUtil finiCocoaUtil] Cleaning up
```

My question (finally!) is:

Is there a way to ensure I clean-up my global resource after all the `NSDocument` instances have been destroyed and stop getting these false negatives?

**EDIT**: I have unhooked the `fullRelease` call and just performed a normal `release` on my resources and Instruments did not detect any memory leaks, so things are OK, but I am curious as to why the `NSDocument` objects don't appear to be being released before `atexit()` is called.

Comment: Be careful how you name your methods. Something starting with `init` is expected to initialize a newly allocated object. It's akin to a C++ constructor. `initialize` might be more appropriate to indicate this sort of use.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Yeah good point WRT `initXxx` method names; I think I will change that!  However, I have tried using `initialize` but wanted more control over when they were called, so set-up to do this manually.

Comment: http://whentouseretaincount.com/

Comment: @bbum Thanks for the flippant remark however "Never" isn't true at all - it's helped me find one over-initialisation of a view already.

Comment: @trojanfoe, that wasn't flippant, it was accurate. It's the most reasonable, useful answer there is.

Comment: @TomHarrington I disagree; the question has been answered and was related to my understanding of the different lifecycle of the `NSDocument` subclass during app quitting.  Did you not see the 'Edit' where I stated I had removed the use of `retainCount` or was it `tl:dr`?

Comment: It wasn't flippant;   `retainCount` is truly a useless method outside of an incredibly narrow (and quite a desperate grasp at straws last effort) use in debugging.

Comment: I think I just died a little inside.  @trojanfoe [the documentation for `-retainCount`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCDAAJI) says: "Do not use this method".  It doesn't get much clearer than that.

Comment: @bbum The question was a bit deeper than that though (see discussion in the answers), plus I already stated I had stopped using it (see the EDIT).  I didn't find it particularly useful, thanks.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Thanks - as I already stated **4 hours ago**, I have stopped using it.  Everyone sees `retainCount` and reads no further...

Comment: Yup -- I added a bunch of notes relevant to your question in an answer below.    I mostly paste that link as a reinforcement to anyone else who might stumble upon this question in the coming year(s).

Comment: To anyone considering downvoting: don't.  The code in the question isn't the greatest, but the *question itself* is a legitimate one.  If anything, it deserves your upvotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Do not release something you do not own!***

Every retain belongs to somebody else. Only send `release` to an object to balance your calls to `new`, `alloc`, `copy`, or `retain` (NARC.) This sort of behaviour will inevitably cause a crash in production code.

It looks like you want to make sure an object is deallocated rather than simply taken care of. If you own the object, release it once; the other references to it belong to other objects. It's possible you *do* have memory leaks in your code (we can't tell just from this code sample) but those can usually be found with the Static Analyzer, Instruments, and a bit of elbow grease.

More importantly: the operating system will free all your memory for you when your process exits. This is not part of the C standard but it is simply how OS X and iOS operate, and it is the expected behaviour on other platforms that support Objective-C. So you don't have to do anything special to clean up when your process exits, except perhaps writing files to disk or similar. In fact, *many Cocoa applications don't bother to release anything owned by their app delegates*, because it's faster to let the operating system dump the memory than it is to call `-release` on thousands of objects.

***Do not call `-retainCount`!***

It lies. Plain and simple. It includes temporary references used by Cocoa, most importantly, and you should *never* attempt to interfere with those. *`-retainCount` is a poisoned symbol.*

Comment: I agree with you, and in this case I am being over-cautious, as already stated.  However why don't my `NSDocument` instances get released before `atexit()` is called?

Comment: They don't get released because nobody actively releases them. Who do you think is responsible for releasing them? Who owns references to them?

Comment: The views (within the `NSDocument` subclass) release the resources in their `dealloc` method.  This isn't happening however (not before `at exit()` is called and the log file is closed, at least).

Comment: That's because `-dealloc` is not called by anybody at process termination. The OS just dumps the used memory immediately.

Comment: Ah, OK that is useful to know.  Seems a bit crass though; the document windows are being closed but you say they aren't released?

Comment: I added logging to my `-close` and `-dealloc` `NSDocument` subclasses and see logging in both when I simply close the window, however I only see logging in `-close` when the app terminates.  I also added a breakpoint in `-dealloc` and that doesn't *trigger* either, so the `NSDocument` doesn't follow the same flow during close and app termination.  You are right.

Comment: `-dealloc` isn't needed during termination because termination implicitly deallocates all memory in the process. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Cheers - I think you've answered the question and I better understand the lifecycle of these objects now.  There was nothing to worry about after all...

Answer (score 7):

Some notes:

- don't use `retainCount`;  see the links on http://whentouseretaincount.com for lots of details
- atexit() handlers are useless in high level programming.  When called, the app is in a relatively undefined state.  The  frameworks will have torn down some stuff but, as you noted, there will be a ton of objects that will never be deallocated.   atexit() may not be called at all, in some cases.
- you cannot rely on app termination to do any kind of required state cleanup.   The user may force quit your app.  The system might, too, or it might be force-rebooted.   At-termination behavior should be treated as an optimization;  can you do some stuff that'll make the next launch faster.
- during app termination, there is no need to deallocate anything.   The system will reclaim all app resources upon termination, regardless of app state.  In other words, *objects left in memory at termination are not leaks*.
- in general, the "Leaks" detection tools can only be used to fix obvious problems.  Leaks only detects memory leaks.  It cannot detect memory accretion where the objects accreted are still connected to a global somehow.   Accretion aren't technically leaks, but they can easily be a huge source of problems.
- [HeapShot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) will detect both leaks and memory accretion.
- Consider migrating your app to use ARC.  One of the guiding patterns of ARC is that the compiler has complete knowledge of the lifespan of objects.   Expressions that are ambiguous under MRR are disallowed under ARC (without proper markup, in some cases).   As well, the ARC compiler and analyzer can do a much deeper analysis of your code, finding many issues that can be quite subtle.

Comment: Cheers - now that *is* a useful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Disable sudden termination, don't use globals, and just use the regular reference counting rules. In some cases, you will need to break strong circular references or manually clear out your objects' instance variables. Finally, it may be more helpful to pause/break before main returns, and run `heap` to see what's really alive (a leak) at this stage.

> I am being over-cautious and attempting to pre-empt memory leaks by using this method to release my global resources.

You should not purge like this - you know better :)

However, locating and destroying all references/objects/allocations which you have control over is actually a very good practice, to ensure your programs work well, are reusable, and as good metrics for monitoring regressions as your apps change.

Comment: Be careful, "destruct manually" sounds like "call `-dealloc`" to Objective-C ears, which is never allowed.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan "For example, break strong circular references" is not clear enough in your opinion? edited.

Comment: The new phrasing is better, yeah. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sudden termination"?  The "globals" in this case is really the `ResourceManager` class that is responsible for loading resources from a zip file and handing them out to users as they want them, which is following the regular reference counting rules.  The use of `retainCount` to check all users have released the resources during app termination has already caught one problem this morning where I was over-retaining some resources, but I cannot get the retain count down to 1, mainly because the views in the document aren't being released themselves...

Comment: @trojanfoe the docs on sudden termination and other life cycle bits are here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/CoreAppDesign/CoreAppDesign.html

Comment: OK, my App doesn't support Sudden Termination, so I think that means I already do everything you mention in your answer.

Comment: @trojanfoe alright, then you might consider locating the imbalances using reference count recording (Instruments->Leaks), then determining how you would go about correcting the imbalances based on the remaining active references.

Comment: Unfortunately Instruments doesn't see any leaks (and "Record Reference Counts" is on by default) so I cannot use that to help.  I think it's just a false negative but I was hoping to understand why, hence my question.  Never mind and thanks for your help!

Comment: @trojanfoe you should not be interested in what is flagged as a leak using this approach -- you simply declare any objects which are still alive when main would return as leaks. those are the ones i am trying to point you to. they don't need to be flagged as leaks by instruments. Leaks' analysis is pessimistic. This tells you what exactly is still alive at exit.

Comment: Sorry I don't really follow you; is this something I should be doing in my app code or something in Instruments?  You say "simply declare any objects...", but how and where do I do that?

Comment: “Disable sudden termination” is rather strong. Sudden termination doesn't cause memory leakage; the memory *will* be cleaned up when your process exits. Sudden termination is only a problem if you have put something outside of your app into a state that you will need to finish and/or clean up—e.g., creating a temporary file, or opening a connection.

Comment: @trojanfoe: You declare it to yourself. Use the Allocations instrument (as pre-configured by the Leaks template) to find which objects are still alive when the process exits. Those are your leaks. Hunt them down as you see fit. (But this only makes sense in a command-line tool. An application is not expected to send `dealloc` to every object at quit, since `-[NSApplication terminate:]` will, after notifying the app's delegate, simply exit immediately—and that's *without* sudden termination.)

Answer (score 2):

As all the others have said: Release *only* what you own. Your app may not crash for you now, but you're just getting lucky. It may crash on another Mac when you do this, or in two hours, or whatever.

If you have a scarce resource that some object is holding on to that *really* needs to be unregistered from (e.g. a network session to another server, where not correctly sending it a sign-off message will cause the server to wait for you, keeping some internal state for your return), you should build *that* into your objects instead of doing that when your objects are released.

E.g. there is a notification that Mac OS X sends before your application quits, NSApplicationWillTerminate. Have your object register for that, and when it gets it, have it send the server its goodbye (and remember that it already did that). That way, when your application quits, but e.g. the application delegate is still holding on to that object, you're still sure that the sign-off will happen.

But you should probably still also check if you've signed off already in -dealloc. One day you might add support for multiple servers, and then when you release one server, you want it to send a goodbye even though your app will not quit. But *only* do the sign off if you haven't done it already.

Same goes for when you have some data in memory that you want to write down before you quit (e.g. that's what NSUserDefaults does to make sure access to preferences is fast, but it still gets written to disk before you quit).

But cases like that are REALLY rare. Usually NSDocument will call you to write to disk when needed, and generally servers notice when the connection drops and clean up by themselves. So you really *shouldn't* release stuff that doesn't belong to you. You'll just cause crashes on quit for some of your users. It gives a really bad impression, and can cause your app to actually fail *before* it got the chance to save some data, and as such make things worse.

Comment: I don't understand why you are assuming I am writing a networking client?

Comment: @trojanfoe: Networking is just one example of a situation in which doing clean-up in `dealloc` is a bad idea. Other examples include timers (if you're targeted by a timer, `dealloc` won't be called anyway, since it owns you) and lock/PID files.